# php array and sub-array

Tags: php, sub-array

I`ve seen the following notation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

What is

```
($users[$data['username']]
```

for?

Is it array and sub array?

Would you please give me a clear example

Thanks

Comment: $users is an array and $data['username'] is a value from the array $data. The code you posted is retrieving the value of $users with the index value of $data['username'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data['username']` is just key for assocative array

```
$data = Array(
  'username' => 'george';
);
$users = Array(
  'george' => "George Clooney",
  'angelina' => "Angelina Jolie"
);

echo $users['george']; // George Clooney
echo $users['angelina']; // Angelina Jolie
echo $users[$data['username']]; // George Clooney
echo $data['username']; // george
```

Answer (score 2):

You should think of it like this:

```
$username = $data['username'];
$user = $users[$username];
```

It uses the value from `$data['username']` as a key in `$users` to find a particular user record.

Answer (score 1):

**$users** is an associate array (see the declaration). **$data['username']** is the key used to extract a specific value from that array.